# Label with bottom edge triangle

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I would like to achieve an effect like on this picture:
[image: desired look of the label]

But I'm not sure if it is possible only with CSS or if I need JS. Right now my label looks like this:
[image]

My css code:

```
.label {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: -5px;
z-index: 1;
display: inline-block;
padding: 1px 20px 1px 24px;
background: #F07D31 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
color: #FFF;
font: 10px/18px "FBold","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0.015em;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/plunker for the same?

Comment: Related question: [Ribbon with “3D” effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504608/styling-menu-with-3d-ribbon-effect)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create ribbon with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829008/create-ribbon-with-css)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This effect is easy to do using a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) which will not require you to alter anything in your HTML:

```css
div {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#f00;
  padding:10px;
}

.label {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: -5px;
 z-index: 1;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 1px 20px 1px 24px;
 background: #F07D31 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
 color: #FFF;
 font: 10px/18px "FBold","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.015em;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.label:before {
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 margin-bottom:-17px;
 margin-left:-20px;
 content:"";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 10px 10px 0;
 border-color: transparent  #904610 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <span class=label>Text goes here</span>
</div>
```

You are basically creating a [css border triangle](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) and positioning it so that it gives the appearance that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

A positioned pseudo-element would work here using the CSS triangles method.

I usually use `em` values here and positioning rather than negative margins. This makes the label adaptable to any text size and doesn't require specific px margin values.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.imgwrap {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.imgwrap img {
  display: block;
}
.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25em 1em;
  background: #F07D31 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  color: #FFF;
  font: 1em "FBold", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.015em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.label:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 .5em .5em 0;
  border-color: transparent #f00 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgwrap">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" />
  <div class="label">My Label</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible using a bit of CSS3.
If you break down the image you're trying to achieve you'll see that all that shaddow is, is basically a darker triangle, hence I've added a div within that `label` div to serve as that triangle:

```
.label .triangle {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 8px 7px 0;
    border-color: transparent #98450f transparent transparent;
}
```

And the HTML I used is:

```
<img src="img.jpg" />
<div class="label"><div class="triangle"></div>PHOTOS</div>
```

That produces this result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS3. There are various online tools available to do this for you. Use these and play around with the parameters to see how it's done.

http://www.css3d.net/ribbon-generator/

Alternatively here is the JSFiddle for an example i quickly created: https://jsfiddle.net/3n22m3v6/

HTML

```
 <div>
  <div class="rectangle">
        </div>
        <div class="triangle-l"></div>
        <div class="triangle-r"></div>
    <img src="" alt="Image here..." />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rectangle {
    background-color: #7f9bd9;
    height: 50px;
    width: 380px;
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
    top: 30px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    z-index: 100;
}

.rectangle h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.triangle-l {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
    top: 65px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-color: transparent #7d90a3 transparent transparent;
}

.triangle-r {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: 350px;
    top: 35px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7d90a3;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Hope this helps :)